# Approach towards Mining Accelerometer Sensor Data

Tags: r, classification, data-mining, prediction

I am a fresher to Data Mining and have some fundamental questions on one of the projects I am working for my College.

Data: We have decided to mine accelerometer and gyroscope sensor readings from a set of 21 individual (for their different activities like walking, jogging, running etc) and come up with a classification solution.

The questions I have are:

1. Since the readings belong to a continuous data (data at a frequency of 50 Hz), 
   how should I sample the data. Would I take a window of data? Are there any standard procedures along this line.
2. What kind of model should I use, that supports for this continuous/sequential data? Is Hidden Markov Model a right approach?
3. Once the model is arrived, will it again take a window (or series ) of data from the test set as input to predict the activity ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is basic Digital Signal Processing questions, and has not much to do with data mining. You should read an introduction to DSP, otherwise you won't really understand what you're doing, and everyone that does might correctly criticize your results.

There's presence in a [Biomed conference proceedings](http://conference.vde.com/bmt-2014/documents/bmt%202014%20dokumente/bmt_2014_program.pdf) that deals with vibroarthrography, i.e. the classification of knee health based on multiple vibration measurements, so you might want to read existing literature.

> Since the readings belong to a continuous data (data at a frequency of 50 Hz), how should I sample the data. Would I take a window of data? Are there any standard procedures along this line.

Yes, you might have to select parts of the data. Typically, you will first have to find a temporal alignment between these datas (typically maximum correlation helps you find that) or you'll need to transfer this kind of data into a time-invariant form (fourier transform, power spectral density etc).

You need to understand what the Nyquist limit is, and you will need solid understanding of signal theory to do something useful with the data.

> What kind of model should I use, that supports for this continuous/sequential data? Is Hidden Markov Model a right approach?

Hidden Markov doesn't make sense for signals of this class at all. Finding a good classificator is a **hard** job, and you will need experience and a lot of trial and error to find a good one. There is no single *right* approach, unless you can mathematically describe your signal exactly enough to prove that there is an optimal classificator. That will require a lot of understanding on how your signal "works".

> Once the model is arrived, will it again take a window (or series ) of data from the test set as input to predict the activity ?

That depends on the model *you* come up with.

**EDIT:** disclaimer: I'm affiliated with that project I cite up there, so I might be biased.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcus.  Great insights, am exploring fourier transform.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called Human Activity Detection in scientific literature, and there are many papers which show different approaches. One recent summarization can be found in Sensors 2017, Volume 17, Issue 3 [A Comprehensive Analysis on Wearable Acceleration Sensors in Human Activity Recognition](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/17/3/529).

> Human Activity Recognition (HAR) starts with collecting data from the motion sensors. Data are partitioned into windows to apply feature extraction thereby filtering relevant information from the raw signals. Afterward, extracted features are used as inputs of each classifier that ultimately the HAR model.
>
> ...We explore 293 different classifiers including Decision Tree, Discriminant Analysis, Support Vector Machines, K-Nearest Neighbors, Ensemble Methods, Naïve Bayes and Neural Network.
>
> ...As a result of the above feature extraction process, a total of 176 features are obtained for each segment and then scaled into interval [0, 1] using min-max normalization so as to be used for classification:
>
> Mean, Minimum, Maximum, Median, Standard Deviation, Skewness, Kurtosis, Signal Power, Root Mean Square, Peak Intensity...